Uniswap v3 Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string
I am attempting to add liquidity to a Uniswap v3 pool using ethers.js, but I keep running into an error. I've successfully created two tokens (token1 and token2) and a liquidity pool using the Uniswap V3 factory contract on a fork of the Ethereum mainnet. However, I can't seem to add liquidity to this pool despite the pool being deployed and the tokens being approved.
Here are the details of my setup:

Ethers.js Version: 5.7.2

Uniswap v3-sdk Version: 3.9.0

Hardhat Version: 2.2.5

Network: Forked Ethereum Mainnet


Below is the code snippet I am using to add liquidity.

const { ethers } = require('ethers');
const { abi: NonfungiblePositionManagerABI } = require('@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/NonfungiblePositionManager.sol/NonfungiblePositionManager.json');
const { abi: UniswapV3FactoryABI } = require('@uniswap/v3-core/artifacts/contracts/UniswapV3Factory.sol/UniswapV3Factory.json');

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545');
const privateKey = 'private_key_here'; 
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);

const nonfungiblePositionManagerAddress = '0xC36442b4a4522E871399CD717aBDD847Ab11FE88';
const factoryAddress = '0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984';
const token1Address = '0x3A906C603F080D96dc08f81CF2889dAB6FF299dE';
const token2Address = '0x18b7CBdfFA52d1e7BB992fd50f394c5b59E20B72';

const nonfungiblePositionManager = new ethers.Contract(
  nonfungiblePositionManagerAddress,
  NonfungiblePositionManagerABI,
  wallet
);

const factory = new ethers.Contract(
  factoryAddress,
  UniswapV3FactoryABI,
  wallet
);

async function addLiquidity() {
  const token0 = token1Address.toLowerCase() < token2Address.toLowerCase() ? token1Address : token2Address;
  const token1 = token1Address.toLowerCase() < token2Address.toLowerCase() ? token2Address : token1Address;
  const fee = 3000;
  const tickLower = -60 * 5;
  const tickUpper = 60 * 5;
  const amount0Desired = ethers.utils.parseUnits('10', 18);
  const amount1Desired = ethers.utils.parseUnits('10', 18);

  const params = {
    token0,
    token1,
    fee,
    tickLower,
    tickUpper,
    amount0Desired,
    amount1Desired,
    amount0Min: 0,
    amount1Min: 0,
    recipient: wallet.address,
    deadline: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 1800, // 30 minutes from now
  };

  try {
    const tx = await nonfungiblePositionManager.mint(params);
    await tx.wait();
    console.log("Liquidity added");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error adding liquidity:', error);
  }
}

addLiquidity();

Here is what I get :
Error adding liquidity: Error: processing response error (body="{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":86,\"error\":{\"code\":-32603,\"message\":\"Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string\",\"data\":{\"message\":\"Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string\",\"txHash\":\"0xaf943a8e98faec13f1665e3461fe1f5fe4cde676fd7b2d666a643bf3a9f0dca7\",\"data\":\"0x\"}}}", error={"code":-32603,"data":{"message":"Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string","txHash":"0xaf943a8e98faec13f1665e3461fe1f5fe4cde676fd7b2d666a643bf3a9f0dca7","data":"0x"}}, requestBody="{\"method\":\"eth_sendRawTransaction\",\"params\":[\"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\"],\"id\":86,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}", requestMethod="POST", url="http://127.0.0.1:8545", code=SERVER_ERROR, version=web/5.7.1)
    at Logger.makeError (uniswap/pool/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:238:21)
    at Logger.throwError (uniswap/pool/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:247:20)
    at uniswap/pool/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:313:32
    at step (uniswap/pool/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:33:23)
    at Object.next (uniswap/pool/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:14:53)
    at fulfilled (uniswap/pool/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:5:58)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  reason: 'processing response error',
  code: 'SERVER_ERROR',
  body: '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":86,"error":{"code":-32603,"message":"Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string","data":{"message":"Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string","txHash":"0xaf943a8e98faec13f1665e3461fe1f5fe4cde676fd7b2d666a643bf3a9f0dca7","data":"0x"}}}',
  error: Error: Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string
      at getResult (uniswap/pool/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:191:21)
      at uniswap/pool/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:356:22)
      at uniswap/pool/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:288:46
      at step (uniswap/pool/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:33:23)
      at Object.next (uniswap/pool/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:14:53)
      at fulfilled (uniswap/pool/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:5:58)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    code: -32603,
    data: {
      message: 'Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string',
      txHash: '0xaf943a8e98faec13f1665e3461fe1f5fe4cde676fd7b2d666a643bf3a9f0dca7',
      data: '0x'
    }
  },
  requestBody: '{"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction","params":["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"],"id":86,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}',
  requestMethod: 'POST',
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8545',
  transaction: {
    type: 2,
    chainId: 31337,
    nonce: 678,
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x59682f00', _isBigNumber: true },
    maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x022056b1a0', _isBigNumber: true },
    gasPrice: null,
    gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x01c9c380', _isBigNumber: true },
    to: '0xC36442b4a4522E871399CD717aBDD847Ab11FE88',
    value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x00', _isBigNumber: true },
    data: '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',
    accessList: [],
    hash: '0xaf943a8e98faec13f1665e3461fe1f5fe4cde676fd7b2d666a643bf3a9f0dca7',
    v: 1,
    r: '0x4ffc7c3bc5fd20f6f367fca6c5f950b0d6886af3db85e3cfeaa5ea8953cf4112',
    s: '0x57746cc2143a4187e0f86fabfe4d424aebe730347ce6dc37d823ad3ca610e685',
    from: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
    confirmations: 0
  },
  transactionHash: '0xaf943a8e98faec13f1665e3461fe1f5fe4cde676fd7b2d666a643bf3a9f0dca7'
}
Transaction details: {
  type: 2,
  chainId: 31337,
  nonce: 678,
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x59682f00', _isBigNumber: true },
  maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x022056b1a0', _isBigNumber: true },
  gasPrice: null,
  gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x01c9c380', _isBigNumber: true },
  to: '0xC36442b4a4522E871399CD717aBDD847Ab11FE88',
  value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x00', _isBigNumber: true },
  data: '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',
  accessList: [],
  hash: '0xaf943a8e98faec13f1665e3461fe1f5fe4cde676fd7b2d666a643bf3a9f0dca7',
  v: 1,
  r: '0x4ffc7c3bc5fd20f6f367fca6c5f950b0d6886af3db85e3cfeaa5ea8953cf4112',
  s: '0x57746cc2143a4187e0f86fabfe4d424aebe730347ce6dc37d823ad3ca610e685',
  from: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
  confirmations: 0
}

Could you help me understand why this error occurs and how to resolve it ?
Thank you.
